# Counting Prime Numbers in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make a program that will count prime numbers.
I tried and tried and it didn't work.
This is the code:

```
def count_primes(num):
primes = 0
if num % num==0 and num  % 1 == 0:
    primes = primes + 1
else:
    pass
return primes
```

I put 100 as the value for num and the program just gives me one.

Comment: 1. You're checking the wrong condition for prime numbers. 2. You only ever check one number, why do you expect an answer different from 1?

Comment: I agree with @Lecdi

Comment: You need to first go back to the basics of what is defined as a prime number: A prime number is one that is not evenly divisible by itself, nor is it evenly divisible by another prime.

Comment: @itprorh66 *"A prime number is one that is not evenly divisible by itself [...]"* - That doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. Your code only checks the number inputted, not all the numbers up to it
2. You check whether the number is divisible by itself and 1, but you don't check whether or not it is divisible by anything else - so any integer will be accepted

The best way to do this is probably to create a list of primes and use a `for` loop to iterate over all the numbers up to the input and check if they are primes. If a number is prime, add it to the list. At the end, return the length of the list.

The reason I would create a list of primes, not just a number, is because this makes testing whether or not a number is prime more efficient - to check if a number is prime it only has to be verified that it is not divisible by any of the primes before it. Here is the completed code:

```py
def count_primes(num):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, num + 1):
        for j in primes:
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
    return len(primes)
```

Here the `for i in range...` is iterating over all the numbers between 2 and `num` and checking if they are prime, adding them to the list if they are. The `for j in primes...` checks if the number is prime by iterating over the current list of primes and checking if the number is divisible by any of them. This is more efficient than checking all the numbers up to `num` because less checks must be made.

If you wanted to be able to specify which number to start counting at, then you would add an aditional `count` variable to store the number of primes currently counted, and only add to the `count` variable if the number was above the starting point:

```py
def count_primes(start, end):
    count = 0
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, end + 1):
        for j in primes:
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
            if i >= start:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: If you don't step by 2, I think it's nicer to [not hardcode 2 as prime](https://tio.run/##XY/BDoIwDIbvPEUvJltEgxgTQ7InMcagFG2EspRx8OnnYCrB/9Z@X5vWvtyj4/3RivcV1nDrBnYXK9Rir3hodZFASGyAgdN5qutOgIAYpOQ7qjyF4MIadh//69jRicMzGEN1mF8FbgxkSzTmKlg@f11selw6ceW2tBa5UqQnKOgGYWiQVeQ6Sf4O3RxSyLP5KXaK0uXTpLX3bw).

Comment: @KellyBundy Good point, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, 1+n//2):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            return False
    
    return True
    

def count_primes(start, end):
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        # if is_prime(i): print(i)
        count = count+1 if is_prime(i) else count
    return count
    
        
count_primes(1,100)
```

Comment: You can replace `if n < 1:` with `if n <= 1:`. Number 1 is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

```
num % num==0 and num  % 1 == 0
```

This won't work, look at the first condition...

```
num % num==0
```

Isn't it always true? The remainder of a division between a number and itself is always `0`.

---

A working condition would be:

```
for i in range(2, n):
    if (n%i==0):
        # Not prime
```

remember that...

> Prime numbers are special numbers that have exactly two factors

one of this factors is the number iself (`i` never reaches `n` since the last value of the `range` is `n-1`), and the other is `1` (`i` starts from 2).

Comment: While this is closer, it still doesn't address the situation where i  maybe divisible by a previously defined prime

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... can you provide a sample value for n that would hit this case?

Comment: prime numbers = [2, 3, 7, 11, 13], note: 9 is missing since it is evenly divisible by 3 which is a prime

Comment: I might add that 5 is also a prime

Comment: @itprorh66, but 9 in fact isn't a prime number...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put together to answer it. The comments that say "for testing" on the end can be uncommented to better understand what is happening in the code. Some of the else statements aren't needed either, but it's for better comprehension. I also have some test cases below. Enjoy! Sincerely, Jaden Taylor

```
def count_primes(num): 
    potentialSuspects = num -1 #chosen range minus 1 because 1 isn't prime
    primeNumbas = [2]
    numPass = False
    for i in range(2,num +1,1): #checks numbers 2 - whatever range we choose
        numPass = False
        for j in primeNumbas:
            currentNumber = i #keeping track of our number outside of loop
            if numPass == False and i > j: #if still a suspect, and not dividing by something larger than itself
                divideTime = i % j
                #print(divideTime) #for testing
                if divideTime == 0:
                    numPass = True #no longer a suspect
                    #print("{} passes the test!".format(i)) #for testing
                    potentialSuspects -= 1
                    #print("Suspects left: {}".format(potentialSuspects)) # for testing
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        if numPass == False: #if statement not needed, but reduces compile time
            primeNumbas.append(i) #this part needed to check against new prime numbers
        else:
            pass
        #numPass is True if notprime, and False if it is prime    
        #print("{} is: {}".format(currentNumber,numPass)) #for testing
    
    print("List of Prime numbers: \n {}".format(primeNumbas)) #only if you wanna see what the prime numbers are
    print("Total prime number count:")
    return potentialSuspects

# Check
print(count_primes(100))
# Check
print(count_primes(150))
# Check
print(count_primes(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer Lecdi gave above is the smiplest. To make his compile time faster, only iterate through every odd number (because all even numbers except 2 are not prime). Example:

```
def count_primes(num): 
    primes = [2]
    for i in range(3, num + 1, 2): #iterate every other
        for j in primes:
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
    return len(primes)
```

Sincerely, Jaden Taylor